# Setup VNC server on ArchLinux with sddm and KDE

Tags: arch-linux, vnc, kde

I'm trying to expose desktop of my PC in internal network. I would like to expose SDDM and KDE session in there. Surprisingly I was not able to find legit article on Arch wiki.

Is it even possible? Or I have to change my assumption? For example hard code plain session with fixed user?